# How to scrape inner html tag data from goutte and return in json format

Tags: php, laravel, web-scraping, scrapy, goutte

I have used a Goutte package in laravel
HTML CODE

```
<div class="middle-stats">
                <div class="wrap">
                    <div class="wrap-inner">
                        <ul class="mediaBodyStats">
                            <li><b>$16.1M</b> Price</li><li><b>47,503</b> Sqft</li><li><b>104.61</b> <div class="middle-stats middle-stats-mobile">
                    </div>
```

Try to access all list item as

```
private product_details = [];
    $page->filter('.middle-stats')->each(function($item){
        print_r($item->text());
        array_push($this->product_details, $item->text());
        

    });
```

how can i add list data in my array from laravel controller

Comment: Cant you send your array from controller when rendering the view?

view('my_view', ['my_array' => $array]);

Comment: it gives all list data in single array but i want to get single li data in 1 array index

Comment: Where is your Scrapy code? What the expected output from that input? What’s the PHP for, how does it it with your Scrapy code?

Comment: Above html code is a scrapy code, expected output is each list item in array index as product_details[0] = price 47,503
product_details[1] = sqft 104.61
............................
Likewise all  list data in index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    private product_details = [];
    $page->filter('.mediaBodyStats > li')->each(function($item){
        array_push($this->product_details, $item->text());
            });
```

> We can use inner html tags with ">" sign